# Sortable unordered list with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

Hello I am needing to create an unordered list that uses jquery to make it sortable.

I want something like is [shown here](http://jsbin.com/okaya4)

How would I do this with ASP.Net? I thought I could just use almost nothing but HTML but it turns out that I need TextBox controls to be in each `<li>`

How would I most easily do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery UI.  It looks like this is pretty much what you're looking for:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Putting a TextBox inside the `<li>` shouldn't make a difference,  the list will still be sortable

Comment: I am using jQuery UI. The point is not doing this in HTML, but doing it with ASP.Net controls.

Comment: Ah yes, well in that case then Canavar's suggestion is the best way to go. You can put the opening ul tag either in the <headertemplate> section or outside the repeater, and the closing ul tag either in the <footertemplate> section or outside of the repeater. Sorry I misunderstood you initially

Comment: Using ASP.NET, how did you store the ordering of the sortable list on post-back?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) that has <li> and the TextBox controls in it's template.

Comment: You could also use a ListView with the layout template having a <ul> and the item template having a <li>.